# SASS change flex layout based on sidebar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the layout of the cards displayed using flex. I have it working when the sidebar is not open. When it is I add a class named "nav-opened" to a parent element but the style is not changing the flex ratios it seems to always be 33.33%.

Is there something I'm missing with my SASS? Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="main-content" [class.nav-opened]="isOpened">
   <div [@reducedMainContent]="marginsReduced ? 'reduced' : 'full'" 
        class="reactive-pane">
      <div class="router" *ngIf="!loading">
           <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thats the HTML.

UPDATE:

```
@media (min-width: 1090px) {
  div.main-content:not(.nav-opened) {
    .card {
      flex: 0 0 33.33%;
      max-width: 33.33%;
    }
  }
  div.nav-opened .card {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

I did not realize that :not checks for the first div that does not contain the class so i made it more specific.

The problem is now its not applying any of the 2 styles.

[image]

This is what it looks like when I don't have the sidebar opened. It looks fine and it works i set the css to just straight up set the .card.

[image]

And here is the problem. Hopefully this helps. In the css above I'm trying to make it become 50% instead of 33% like the picture below.

Comment: Is this SASS? If not, you can’t nest css selectors like that. Should be div:not(.nav-opened) .card {...}

Comment: Yes it is SASS sorry let me update

Comment: Please post your html. Hard to find the issue without seeing the page structure.

Comment: sure give me a minute. its using angular. also i updated the css im getting closer but still not working. ill update my newest changes

Comment: Thanks  scratching my head on this one for the moment. I was able to put together a quick test an my version was working. I figured there’s more going on somewhere

Comment: There the .card class is a component in the router-outlet. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Very helpful actually. I see what’s going on now. Just need to write it into an answer. Short version: the not pseudo selector is funky in how it treats ancestors

Comment: Thanks this has been bugging me all day

Comment: I’ll be getting back to you soon. Haven’t had a chance to write it up yet.

Comment: I'm having so much trouble writing this explanation out. I'm going to need to see what the final rendered html looks like. It has to do with using the descendant selector in your `:not` pseudo-class. You need to be more specific on what gets excluded is the short answer.

Comment: I don't have my work computer on me right now but i can draw out what it looks like if that helps? or else I can get it for you tomorrow

Comment: I posted up the images hopefully that will help you see the issue :)

Comment: I added my answer that worked for me, but I am willing to see yours if you solved it in a different way. Maybe it can help more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up researching and it seems when working with different components we need to use :host-context for angular to be able to refer to other components classes.

```
@media (min-width: 1090px) {
  .card {
    flex: 0 0 33.33%;
    max-width: 33.33%;
  }
  :host-context(div.nav-opened) .card{
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Here is the working code. Hopefully this helps someone else so they do not go crazy trying to find the answer like I did.